# Where to put css and javascript files in gradle java web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gradle

I followed the steps for building java web application using the following guide
https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-web-applications/

Now there is no web.xml generated. Trying to find out where to put my css and javascript files so that they can be accesible in jsp and html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static resources should go in src/main/webapp.  Anything in this folder will be copied into the root of the war file.

For Example, if you place the following index.html and site.css in src/main/webapp, you should get a page with Hello, World in blue text.

index.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="site.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, World</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

site.css

```
    h1 {
        color: blue;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Dusty,  I was putting css and javascript files in webapp folder but I was using forward slash (/)  like this <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css">. I removed the forward slash and it worked.